# How to save and access large data in "auxiliary" file in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am new to visual basic and to learn how to program using this language I am building myself a thermodynamics properties calculator. For that, I can work with multiple fluids (like water, air, etc.), multiple properties (density, conductivity, etc) and multiple coefficients.

Right now I have a 9th degree polynomial to calculate each property, so that will be 10 coefficients for each property and in total 16 properties, right now i am working with only 2 fluids.

I would like an opinion about how to store the data. Right now, I created the variable coeffs, which stores the data in a matrix form.

```
Dim coeffs(2, 16, 10) As Double
```

where the data would be in the form coeffs(Fluid,Property,Coefficient), and each fluid, property, and coefficient is related to a number, e.g. Water = 1, Air = 2, Density = 1, ...

And in the Form1_Load I define the values itself, like this:

```
coeffs(1, 1, 1) = -7.5034535361242876 * 10 ^ (-22)
    coeffs(1, 1, 2) = 2.9086161180361931 * 10 ^ (-18)
    coeffs(1, 1, 3) = -4.9611705760075973 * 10 ^ (-15)
```

So, as you can see, there would be 160 lines of code for just one fluid, so it begins to get a little messy in the main Form. What I would like to do, to keep it simple, is to save the variable coeffs into another .vb file in the solution explorer, let's say Coeffs_File.vb and access it from the Form1.vb file, but I have little ideia on how to do it. I have tried creating a Public Shared variable and I was able to call it from the main Form, however, it always returned zero during the calling.

Best Regards,

Guaraldi

ME UGDR

Comment: One way to save a small amount of data like that is to serialize it. You might also be able to create a class that calculates the desired value on the fly rather than recalculating them all, every time.  Essentially you'd code the formulae and constants rather than coding the result(s).

Comment: @Plutonix The values are not recalculated every time, those are the coefficients used to calculate the values. They are a polynomial of the form: p(x) = p1*x^9 + p2*x^8 + p3*x^7 + ... + p9*x^1 + p10. The result to be shown is p(x) and the parameter "x" is given by the user in a Text box.

Comment: `-7.5034535361242876 * 10 ^ (-22)` is a calculation resulting in a value.  You are asking about ways of saving/storing/implementing *those values* and that is what I was referring to,

Comment: The usual way of writing -7.5034535361242876 * 10 ^ (-22) on a computer is -7.5034535361242876E-22. [Wikipedia: E notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation).

Comment: What I intended to do is simply to "save" those coefficients in another file, let's say Coeffs_File.vb and to make the variable coeffs( , , ) accessible by the main form Form1.vb.